# Jenkins : Copy artifacts from Multibranch pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am new to Jenkin's and I have 4 repo's in Bitbucket say A,B,C,D.
I have to fetch the A,B & C repos, build them using **gradle build** which will generate wars.
Now I have to copy those wars in D\warsFolder
I have created Multibranch pipeline and generated the pipeline syntax which fetches A,B & C from git and builds them. Looks some thing like this

```
    node {
    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: 'A']], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'id', url: 'http://.../A.git']]])
    dir('A') {
        bat 'gradle build -i --info --stacktrace --debug'
    }
    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: 'B']], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'id', url: 'http://.../B.git']]])
    dir('B') {
        bat 'gradle build -i --info --stacktrace --debug'
    }
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: 'C']], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'id', url: 'http://.../C.git']]])
    dir('C') {
        bat 'gradle build -i --info --stacktrace --debug'
    }

    }
```

added the above script in Jenkinsfile which I placed in A repo.

Now I have created a Multibranch pipeline **Fetch_all** and in branch sources -> Single repository & branch -> Repository URL I have added http://.../A.git (which has Jenkinsfile).
Upto here everything is working fine I am able to fetch the sources and build them.

I have created new job  of Freestyle where in Source Code Management -> Git -> Repository URL will be http://.../D.git.
I am trying to copy the wars generated in the **Fetch_all** pipeline but in Build -> Copy artifacts from another project the Project Name is not accepting the Multibranch pipeline. It is throwing error like

```
ERROR: Unable to find project for artifact copy: 
This may be due to incorrect project name or permission settings; see help for project name in job configuration.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally got it, when I gave pipeline_name/branchname i.e., Fetch_all/%00 it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

It took some time to find out the correct syntax. The documentations of the [Coyartifact Plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/copyartifact/) is a little bit confusing, as it mentions the [encoding of special characters](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/How+to+reference+another+project+by+name). Actually spaces don't have to be encoded, but slashes have to.

The Jenkinsfile which copies artifacts is located at 'Other-folder/Multi branch Pipeline Test/', put in this content to copy the artifact of the last successfull build of the 'Folder/Multi branch Pipeline/feature%2Fallow-artifact-copy' project

```
copyArtifacts(
    projectName: 'Folder/Multi branch Pipeline/feature%2Fallow-artifact-copy',// the name of project, as you find it from the root of jenkins
    selector: lastSuccessful(),             // selector to select the build to copy from. If not specified, latest stable build is used.
    filter: 'projects/Output/myzip.zip',    // ant-expression to filter artifacts to copy, Attention! Filter is case sensitive
    target: 'sources/deploy/',              // target directory to copy to, intermediate folders will be created
    flatten: true,                          // ignore directory structures of artifacts, Artifact will be placed at 'sources/deploy/myzip.zip'. Is the option false, you find it at 'projects/Outpu/myzip.py'
    optional: false,                        // do not fail the step even if no appropriate build is found.
    fingerprintArtifacts: true,             // fingerprint artifacts to track builds using those artifacts
)
```

And don't forget to allow artifact copy in the project you want to take the artifact from. Add this to the Jenkinsfile of 'Folder/Multi branch Pipeline/feature%2Fallow-artifact-copy'. Use absolute paths, to avoid issues if you move some projects around.

```
options {
     disableConcurrentBuilds()
     timeout(time: 30, unit: 'MINUTES')
     copyArtifactPermission('/Other-folder/Multi branch Pipeline Test/*, /second Folder/*') // allow all the projects or branches of 'Other-folder/Multi branch Pipeline Test' and 'second Folder' to copy artifacts of this job
} // end of options
```